# GenericJson doesn't retain null value

Tags: google-api-java-client, google-api-client

I'm doing Google calendar sync in Java, having problem like this: 
I have to post an EventDateTime (subclass of GenericJson) to Google to sync the time. Especially in my case I have to clear the "date" field, and set the "dateTime" field.

```
   //code to init the variable dateTime, in the form of google DateTime
   EventDateTime edt = new EventDateTime();
   edt.put("dateTime", dateTime);
   edt.put("date", null);
```

When I use the code above, the map inside edt just shows 1 `<key,value>` pair: `<dateTime,some date>`. There is no value pair `<date,null>`.

Anyone experience this? pls help me with a workaround.
tks.

Updated: this works: `edt.put ("date", Data.NULL_DATE_TIME)`, the idea is go inside the code of Data, find the corresponding field NULL_XXX and pick what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Data.NULL_STRING](http://javadoc.google-http-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.13.1-beta/com/google/api/client/util/Data.html#NULL_STRING) for the value instead of null.

There's more detailed documentation about how we handle JSON null [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/JSON#JSON_null).

NOTE: I'm a project owner of [google-http-java-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/).

Comment: Hi, tks for answer and sorry for late reply. When I tried your solution, there's an error: `ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.google.api.client.util.DateTime field com.google.api.services.calendar.model.EventDateTime.dateTime to java.lang.String`

Comment: oh, NULL_DATE_TIME works,tks .Updated in my post, can you update your answer so I can tick (just for others to see immediately), cheers.